# Method naming in TDD or BDD when doing the simplest thing that can possibly work

Tags: java, junit, tdd, bdd

For example, I have to create Vector class that can return vectors length.

First I add test:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnLengthOfVector() {
    Vector3D vector = new Vector3D(4d, 2d, -4d);

    assertThat(vector.length(), is(6d));
}
```

While writing test, create class Vector3D and add method stub.

```
public double length() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

Test do not pass. What is simples thing to pass the test? Hard coded value:

```
public double length() {
    return 6d;
}
```

Test passes. Now I add some method that checks "cornercase":

```
@Test
public void someCornercaseShouldReturnLengthOfVector() {
    Vector3D vector = new Vector3D(1d, -2d, -2d);

    assertThat(vector.length(), is(3d));
}
```

Of-course that does not pass. I change my implementation:

```
public double length() {
    return Math.sqrt(i * i + j * j + k * k);
}
```

Everything is green!

**How to pick names for methods when I follow "simplest thing that can possibly work" principle?** In this example method `someCornercaseShouldReturnLengthOfVector` and that is't good name.

Comment: What's the point of the step where you hard code a value to return in `length()`? You are just going to replace this in a few steps later on. Why make tests pass just for the sake of passing?

Comment: @matt b I am following 3 laws of TDD. Expectation in test is still valid and gives me a starting point - after it is green it should stay so, or something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing that could possibly work is to add another assertion to `shouldReturnLengthOfVector`:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnLengthOfVector() {
    Vector3D v1= new Vector3D(4d, 2d, -4d);
    assertThat(v1.length(), is(6d));

    Vector3D v2 = new Vector3D(1d, -2d, -2d);
    assertThat(v2.length(), is(3d));
}
```

I realize that some people believe that each test should have a single assertion. However, I think it is more useful *as documentation of behavior* if you give several examples of "normal" operation, and reserve separate test cases for true corner cases (eg, passing NaN).

Another approach is to be more specific with your test naming. In this case, you *wouldn't* create a test "should return length of vector." Instead, you'd create a bunch of methods, like "identical values are zero length," "vectors that have length 1" (which could have lots of assertions, varying the different parameters), "vectors with negative values," and so on.

Comment: I tend to agree that doggedly following the "one assertion per test" rule can result in some ugly and unwieldy test suites.

Comment: Enlightenment! I have got several assumptions wrong: 1) I wasn't doing simplest thing (it would be Vector3D(0,0,0)), 2) example doesn't illustrate the problem, because there is no real corner case 3) my test method naming was to broad - it must be more specific to illustrate behavior being tested.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unit test for; Is the meaning of this method clear.  You have to use your judgement.

The simplest name which would work is just `l` ;)  You should also think about clarity when determining what you can work with. i.e. you have to consider the developer(s) as well as the what the compiler will let you get away with.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your test code too.  `someCornercaseShouldReturnLengthOfVector` is a perfectly valid name while you're at the "simplest thing that can possibly work" phase.  Refactor the name to reflect what the code actually tests once you're further along in your testing.

You can also *comment* your test code to make its intent more clear.  ;)

Comment: "... the only truly good comment is the
comment you found a way not to write." -- Rober. C. Martin. So I would like to avoid them.

Comment: After more functionality add, this method still would be valid, so refactoring would affect only its name.

Comment: @janis: Isn't its name exactly what your question is about?

Comment: It is. So I am struggling with coming up with some good name. @brainimus answer was my first though, but it is not working well enough if input is complex.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the following pattern when naming my methods:

`WhatImTesting_WhatAreTheImputs_ExpectedResult`

Just because it is a simple and clear case to you doesn't mean it is to everyone else.  Although my method naming can get wordy it is normally very clear what they are testing.  To use your example I would name my method something like `Length_ValidConstructorImputs_CorrectLength()` this way just by reading the method name I know that we are testing the length method with valid inputs (from the constructor) and the correct length should be returned.

For another example suppose I wanted to test the following constructor:

```
public class House
{
    Door theDoor;
    public House(Door aDoor)
    {
        if(aDoor == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        theDoor = aDoor;
    }
}
```

I would probably have two methods to test this:

- `Constructor_ValidDoor_ObjectCreated()`: This would check that the House object is created when the constructor parameter is valid.
- `Constructor_NullDoor_ExceptionThrown()`: This would check that an exception is thrown when a null parameter is passed into the constructor.

Comment: It is tricky, because if I have negative values, method name gets really ugly.

Comment: I agree.  The method names can be long and a bit wordy.  I'm ok with this in tests though since I want to be able to read the method name and know exactly what is tested and if one fails I've got a pretty good idea of where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the case here I would either have followed Anon's advice and put a second assertion into the same test, neatly dodging the naming question, or, if religious about the "one assertion per test" rule, have named the next test `shouldReturnLengthOfAnotherVector`.